# Rails Workspace - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994430+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994377 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/contacts"):
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994509+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994457 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061]   
2017-02-27T11:06:42.993179+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.993087 #4]  INFO -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] Started GET "/contacts" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:42 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994584+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994532 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994668+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994609 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994829+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994690 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994974+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994924 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995205+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995148 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.994902+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994851 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995265+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995212 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995045+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.994994 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995324+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995278 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995146+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995074 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995356+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995323 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995393+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995355 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995426+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995394 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995496+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995473 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995597+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995565 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995628+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995596 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995728+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995675 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995492+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995426 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995789+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995734 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995529+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995498 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:42.995565+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:06:42.995527 #4] FATAL -- : [a69eb1bb-e3e2-40e6-8ae1-d190f82ff061] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
2017-02-27T11:06:43.892610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=feb02714-5195-49b4-ba01-118276bdf82e fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-27T11:06:51.623329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=2566
2017-02-27T11:06:51.562351+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:51.562230 #4]  INFO -- : [90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc] Started GET "/" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:51 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:51.567041+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:51.566932 #4]  INFO -- : [90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2017-02-27T11:06:51.568739+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:51.568659 #4]  INFO -- : [90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:06:51.569017+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:51.568948 #4]  INFO -- : [90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:51.582560+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:51.582474 #4]  INFO -- : [90703699-ffbe-4763-aef9-03e9e460ebdc] Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:51.977680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-312ef2b69741beaa2e750d8fa449d2ea1f77ba1ed9a8fc30ba8cadc2ccc40f06.css" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=17773a20-713c-45d5-b54c-29d6106f6023 fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-27T11:06:52.194824+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-95163fa38446d1bb6139f870d5fb932af7fa47b347b8951923c32a4565386aa6.js" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=0b17b5bd-f27d-4e40-9489-b78c035cf31c fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-27T11:06:52.595269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-2932abf996373e87fbf2e950876b1962f1b57db954a1643ea68831d9fbb74da4.woff2?v=4.6.2" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=a11f2a2f-abc8-4da8-8e14-26b66276a880 fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-27T11:06:54.019857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact-us" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=3608
2017-02-27T11:06:54.009940+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:54.009857 #4]  INFO -- : [82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc] Started GET "/contact-us" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:54 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:54.011121+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:54.011066 #4]  INFO -- : [82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc] Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2017-02-27T11:06:54.012881+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:54.012808 #4]  INFO -- : [82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc]   Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:06:54.016686+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:54.016631 #4]  INFO -- : [82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:54.018056+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:54.017996 #4]  INFO -- : [82c53527-f24d-4ed8-8bd1-c0703f1215dc] Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:55.222640+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:55.222541 #4]  INFO -- : [8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714] Started GET "/about" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:55 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:55.223518+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:55.223449 #4]  INFO -- : [8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714] Processing by PagesController#about as HTML
2017-02-27T11:06:55.224508+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:55.224434 #4]  INFO -- : [8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714]   Rendering pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:06:55.224733+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:55.224667 #4]  INFO -- : [8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714]   Rendered pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:55.225716+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:55.225655 #4]  INFO -- : [8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714] Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:55.227577+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=8dc99f1d-a34c-442a-ab1e-04c74bf8f714 fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=2558
2017-02-27T11:06:56.235790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact-us" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=3608
2017-02-27T11:06:56.226868+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:56.226794 #4]  INFO -- : [513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd] Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2017-02-27T11:06:56.232016+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:56.231940 #4]  INFO -- : [513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:56.225920+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:56.225817 #4]  INFO -- : [513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd] Started GET "/contact-us" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:56 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:56.233254+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:56.233182 #4]  INFO -- : [513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd] Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:56.228266+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:56.228196 #4]  INFO -- : [513667f8-6883-4cd0-bd87-c036e66152dd]   Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:06:58.337233+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=2566
2017-02-27T11:06:58.331513+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:58.331421 #4]  INFO -- : [6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b] Started GET "/" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:06:58 +0000
2017-02-27T11:06:58.332473+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:58.332413 #4]  INFO -- : [6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2017-02-27T11:06:58.333761+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:58.333701 #4]  INFO -- : [6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:06:58.333986+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:58.333931 #4]  INFO -- : [6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2017-02-27T11:06:58.335462+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:06:58.335404 #4]  INFO -- : [6da8eb1d-6739-4e64-af60-19ef10f0a19b] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:00.035299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact-us" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=3608
2017-02-27T11:07:00.028387+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:00.028288 #4]  INFO -- : [42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c] Started GET "/contact-us" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:07:00 +0000
2017-02-27T11:07:00.029299+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:00.029226 #4]  INFO -- : [42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c] Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2017-02-27T11:07:00.030714+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:00.030597 #4]  INFO -- : [42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c]   Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-27T11:07:00.032896+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:00.032788 #4]  INFO -- : [42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:00.033962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:00.033918 #4]  INFO -- : [42a1dae6-3610-401f-864a-29108f7feb9c] Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:13.142879+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.142775 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Started POST "/contacts" for 146.88.42.245 at 2017-02-27 11:07:13 +0000
2017-02-27T11:07:13.143858+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.143793 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2017-02-27T11:07:13.143964+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.143903 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WUcwQ958ZsMIXgIXvrkjnrZpId1LbTHWiQ7jizMJFGwu8uZGQW7/N6HdHXrXSeuMRVeGLassdzc2KjwPLvdtPw==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"lets", "email"=>"try@example.com", "comments"=>"again"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2017-02-27T11:07:13.167660+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.167417 #4] DEBUG -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]    (8.4ms)  BEGIN
2017-02-27T11:07:13.182380+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.182279 #4] DEBUG -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("name", "email", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "lets"], ["email", "try@example.com"], ["comments", "again"], ["created_at", 2017-02-27 11:07:13 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-27 11:07:13 UTC]]
2017-02-27T11:07:13.191933+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.191866 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb
2017-02-27T11:07:13.192862+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.192797 #4] DEBUG -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 1.9ms
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346238+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.346127 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Sent mail to joshsad2@gmail.com (153.1ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346299+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.346236 #4] DEBUG -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2017 11:07:13 +0000
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346301+00:00 app[web.1]: From: try@example.com
2017-02-27T11:07:13.190448+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.190243 #4] DEBUG -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]    (7.4ms)  COMMIT
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346302+00:00 app[web.1]: To: joshsad2@gmail.com
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346303+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <58b40861327e6_43fef7a4369905124b@337d512e-6d9e-49f8-bcbc-ea4273c0578a.mail>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346303+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Contact Form Message
2017-02-27T11:07:13.192130+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.192065 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.1ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346305+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346306+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346308+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346308+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346304+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346309+00:00 app[web.1]:   <head>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346305+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346310+00:00 app[web.1]:   </head>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346310+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346312+00:00 app[web.1]:     lets, try@example.com.</p>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346313+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346314+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346621+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.346555 #4]  INFO -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 202ms (ActiveRecord: 17.3ms)
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346311+00:00 app[web.1]:     <p>You have received a message from the site's contact form, from
2017-02-27T11:07:13.347447+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.347378 #4] FATAL -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   
2017-02-27T11:07:13.347521+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.347452 #4] FATAL -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
2017-02-27T11:07:13.346313+00:00 app[web.1]:     <p>again</p>
2017-02-27T11:07:13.347522+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-02-27T11:07:13.347577+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.347523 #4] FATAL -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd]   
2017-02-27T11:07:13.347639+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-27T11:07:13.347582 #4] FATAL -- : [8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:12:in `create'
2017-02-27T11:07:13.348452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=morning-tor-56053.herokuapp.com request_id=8180032d-3f14-4494-8521-819bc13308fd fwd="146.88.42.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=213ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

It's really messy and I'm already positive I verified my account if that's the problem. My practice site is working, however. It's just when sending information via the contact us page, I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Comment: I can see this error at the first line `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/contacts"):`

Comment: Yes @DeepakMahakale, same, I think the problem is in routes.

Answer (score 0):

As the log says, fix your Mailgun account.

> Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.